# Error in checking the key code

Tags: javascript

I am working on making a small game of tic tac toe. I am using javascript to code. The problem I am facing is that I am getting a warning in js console

```
'KeyboardEvent.keyLocation' is deprecated. Please use 'KeyboardEvent.location' instead.
```

And after getting this warning in console.I am not able to use the keys further.I have a function that will check the pressed keys.The code is

```
window.onkeyup=function()
{
    var current_key = event.keyCode;
    console.log(current_key);
    if(current_key == 37) goleft();
    if(current_key == 38) goup();
    if(current_key == 39) goright();
    if(current_key == 40) godown();
}
```

How can I get rid of this problem.

Comment: Try passing 'function(**event**)'

Answer (score 0):

Pass `event` to your function like this:

```
window.onkeyup = function(event) {
    var current_key = event.keyCode;
    console.log(current_key);
    if(current_key == 37) goleft();
    if(current_key == 38) goup();
    if(current_key == 39) goright();
    if(current_key == 40) godown();
};
```

Answer (score -1):

did you do anything similar to this:

on the `keyPress` event of the object use something like: `keyPress="doSomething(event)"`

then the js:

```
function doSomething(e){
  if (e.keyCode == "13") {
     //do Somehing
  }
}
```